# spring-Integration - http inbound-gateway response and asynchronous processing - task executor threads just processing one message instead of all

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-integration

Description:

We have a Spring Integration flow where we want to have an endpoint configured, split the payload, return to the consumer i.e. with a http code 202 and the other items must continue to be processed asynchronous.

Explanation of the configuration:

We have a `<int-http:inbound-gateway>`. We split `<int:splitter>` the incoming payload. The `splitter` creates always a list were the 1st message of the list is the `MAIN` and then the following would be the `ITEM` messages.

In the `<int:header-value-router` with input channel: `mainItemRouter-channel` The `MAIN` message will answer to the receiver thread so that the consumer of the API get a 202. The `ITEM` messages needs to be processed asynchronously even the consumer already received a 202.

The problem:

If i have i.e. a list of 25 (1 `MAIN` and 24 `ITEM`) messages after the splitter the `taskExecutor` threads just process 10. Which means each thread just processes one message and then stops.

Why do the `taskExecutor` threads not pick up the other 14 messages to process?

Do all the 24 `ITEM` messages even reach the executor-channel?

This is the configuration:

```
<beans>
    <int:channel id="postInboundReply-channel"/>
    <int:header-enricher input-channel="postFinish-channel" output-channel="postInboundReply-channel">
        <int:header name="myHeader" overwrite="true"
                    expression="setMyHeader"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <!-- Endpoint -->
    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="postInbound-gateway"
                              request-channel="postInboundRequest-channel"
                              reply-channel="postInboundReply-channel"
                              supported-methods="POST"
                              path="/api/tests"
                              request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                              mapped-request-headers="content-type,Authorization"
                              mapped-response-headers="Content-Type,Location,myHeader"
                              >
        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" produces="application/json"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>


    <!-- split payload -->
    <int:splitter id='splitter' ref='splitterObject' method='split'
                  input-channel='postInboundRequest-channel' output-channel='mainRouter-channel'/>

    <!--  MAIN gives the response to the http request, ITEM must continue asychronously -->
    <int:header-value-router input-channel="mainRouter-channel"  default-output-channel="executor-channel" header-name="myType">
        <int:mapping value="MAIN" channel="httpResponse-channel"/>
        <int:mapping value="ITEM" channel="executor-channel"/>
        <int:mapping value="ERROR" channel="postFinish-channel"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:transformer input-channel="httpResponse-channel"
                     output-channel="postFinish-channel"
                     ref="responderObject"/>

    <!-- execute items in parallel -->
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10" rejection-policy="DISCARD"/>
    <int:channel id="executor-channel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:transformer input-channel="executor-channel"
                     output-channel="afterTransformation1-channel"
                     ref="aTransformationBean"/>

    <int:transformer input-channel="afterTransformation1-channel"
                     output-channel="afterTransformation2-channel"
                     ref="aTransformationBean2"/>

    <!-- ITEM continues, ERROR has finished -->
    <int:header-value-router input-channel="afterTransformation2-channel" default-output-channel="nullChannel" header-name="myType">
        <int:mapping value="ITEM" channel="ItemAsyncPrcGatewayChain-channel"/>
        <int:mapping value="ERROR" channel="nullChannel"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <!-- wrap the whole async  process in a chain in order to catch exceptions in the error-channel -->
    <int:chain input-channel="ItemAsyncPrcGatewayChain-channel">
      <int:gateway id="itemAsyncPrcGateway" request-channel="itemAsyncProcess-channel" error-channel="asyncProcessError-channel"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:transformer input-channel="asyncProcessError-channel"
                     ref="asyncExceptionHandler"/>

    <int:chain input-channel="itemAsyncProcess-channel" output-channel="nullChannel">
        <int:transformer ref="asyncTransformerBean"/>
        <int:transformer ref="asyncSendJmsMessageBean"/>
        <int:transformer ref="asyncStoreStateBean"/>
    </int:chain>

</beans>
```

run several tests with different configuration without success

Comment: But you said it yourself: `rejection-policy="DISCARD"`. So, that means the task executor will accept 10 tasks and drop the rest since all its threads are busy.

Comment: I dont define a `queue-capacity` which means according to the documentation i have an `unbounded queue` and how i interpret the documentation the `rejection-policy` has no effect. Removed `rejection-policy` and also tried `pool-size="0-10"` does not work either, as before the 10 threads just pick up one message and after the 10 are finished the 10 threads dont pick up the next message from the queue. I thought with this configuration i can define that:  `max. 10 threads will process in parallel` the messages in the `executor-channel queue`

Answer (score 0):

OK. I see your problem.

You do `<int:gateway id="itemAsyncPrcGateway">` inside a `<chain>`. And this is is about a request-reply. Its contract is based on the:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RequestReplyExchanger {

    Message<?> exchange(Message<?> request) throws MessagingException;

}
```

However in the end of that gateway's sub-flow you do:

```
<int:chain input-channel="itemAsyncProcess-channel" output-channel="nullChannel">
```

therefore you don't return any reply to that gateway. It is probably what you would expect in the end of each item process, but then your `<gateway>` in the middle is wrong.

How about just get rid of that `<int:chain input-channel="ItemAsyncPrcGatewayChain-channel">` and route the item directly to the `itemAsyncProcess-channel`?

The point is that gateway is waiting for reply blocking a thread it working in.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for the reply. When i remove the `<int:chain input-channel="ItemAsyncPrcGatewayChain-channel">` the processing works but i can not catch the exceptions anymore (thrown i.e. by the bean `asyncSendJmsMessageBean` ) which i want to handle in the `asyncProcessError-channel` that is why i configured the gateway and wrapped it into a chain. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Sure! That also possible. See `reply-timeout="0"` on the `<gateway>` or use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` for the specific endpoint you'd like to handle errors on: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice

Comment: Dont see how i could use your proposal for my usecase. The exceptions i want to catch and handle are not on the endpoint level.They are thrown in the async process and the main thread has already returned to the endpoint request with i.e. 202. In the async process several messages will be processed.Some will be processed fine and some will fail. I want to process all messages which come from the `splitter`. The messages which failes by an exception just go on another channel.

Comment: Please see original configuration, if i.e. in the bean `asyncSendJmsMessageBean` there is no exception i continue in the flow  but if there is exception i want to jump to `asyncProcessError-channel` to handle the exception, just for this one message which has an exception, in the bean `asyncExceptionHandler`, when this one exception i handled for this one message the thread should pick the next message to process.

Comment: Your problem that the gateway withing the `<chain>` is waiting for reply when everything is OK. You got an exception on a sending thread, so just having `reply-timeout="0"` should be enough for your current expectations.